# How can I count calls to a looped Promise function with Jest

Tags: jestjs

I have a function:

```
myFunc = async () => {
  for (let item of items) {
      await doSomething(items);
  }
}
```

I use `for of` loop because it respects await.

My test:

```
it('should call doSomething twice', () => {
  const doSomething = jest.fn();
  const items = [{a: 'a'}, {b: 'b'}];
  myFunc(items);
  expect(doSomething).toBeCalledTimes(2);
})
```

It fails because `doSomething` is only called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wait for all the iterations to be completed.

Try something like this:

```js
it('should call doSomething twice', async () => {
  const doSomething = jest.fn();
  const items = [{a: 'a'}, {b: 'b'}];
  // Waiting
  await myFunc(items);
  expect(doSomething).toBeCalledTimes(2);
})
```